# Phantom html-to-pdf Document broken

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, ejs, html-to-pdf

I am using Phantom-html-to-pdf to create documents. In my node application I create an HTML string with EJS templating then I save the documents into a folder.

In my EJS file I import css file, but it seems like for 20% of the PDF generated the css is not loaded.
So the error is that the font is not loaded and i got blank PDF even with fallback font

My function:

```js
function createPdf  (data, template, directory) {

    var options = {};
    var type = template.indexOf('avoir') >= 0 ? true : false
    var tva = [];
    var items = listeItem(data);
    var list = calculeTva(data.Liste_item, type);

    Societe.findOne({}, (err, doc) => { 
        data.Liste_tva = list ;
        data.societe = doc ;
        data.items = items ;

        var html = ejs.renderFile(__dirname + `/template/${template}.ejs`,  {data: data}, options, function(err, str){
            if(err){
                return err
            }
            return str
        });

        var option = {
            html : html,
        }

        var filename = directory === 'archive' ? data.Référence + '-' + Date.now() : data.Référence;

        var conversion = require("phantom-html-to-pdf")(); 

        // var conversion = require("phantom-html-to-pdf")({
        //     phantomPath: require("phantomjs-prebuilt").path
        // });

        conversion({ 
            html: html, 
            paperSize: {
                format: 'A4',
                orientation: 'portrait',
                margin: {bottom: '0cm', left: '0.5cm', right: '0.5cm', top: '0.5cm'},
            }
        }, function(err, pdf) {
            console.log('ERR', err)
            var output = fs.createWriteStream(`documents/${directory}/${filename}.pdf`)
            pdf.stream.pipe(output);

            response = {success: false, err: err}
            return response        

        });

    });
}
```

My EJS :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link  rel="stylesheet" href="https://mywebsite.com/css/uikitx.css" />
 <link   href="https://mywebsite.com/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body style="font-family: 'AvenirNext', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
```

I really stuck on this, any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you still need help with this or have you solved the question?

Comment: Can anyone provide a solution? The documentation is so little that I can't get much useful info there.

Comment: I decided to go with wkhtmltopdf - For the font problem I uploaded the font into my server /locale/shared/font/